# Testing RejectedExecutionHandler in ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading

How i can make sure that my rejectedExecution method works

```
 RejectedExecutionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Name_[" + executorServiceName + "]: All threads busy, processing inline.");
            r.run();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would personally create a situation where my `ExecutorService` **will always reject a task** and check that this task has been called using a counter.

So for example my code could be something like that:

```
// A single threaded executor service that cannot have more than 1 task in its task queue
// such that I know that if I provide at least 3 tasks, at least 1 task will be rejected. 
// Why 3? 1 task in the queue + 1 task executed by the thread of the pool 
// = max of tasks that the pool can manage at a given time, so if I add 1 it will be
// rejected.
ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
    1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(1),
    Executors.defaultThreadFactory(), myHandler
);

// My Counter
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
// Some arbitrary task that lasts long enough to make sure that at least 3
// tasks will be submitted that will increment my counter once completed
Runnable task = () -> {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1_000L);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    } finally {
        counter.incrementAndGet();
    }
};
try {
    // Submit 3 tasks
    executor.submit(task);
    executor.submit(task);
    executor.submit(task);
} finally {
    // Shutdown the pool and wait until all the submitted tasks have been executed
    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(1L, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
// Ensure that we have 3 tasks that have been executed
assertEquals(3, counter.get());
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I am trying to test it outside the class and i cannot make changes to existing class for shutting down. This way can test it stand alone. Is there any way to test it with Unit Test or any other way?

Comment: all this code can go into a test method of your Unit Test class, the only thing to provide is myHandler